# Java code in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I'm using certain `java` custom libraries in my `Xamarin Forms` project.

To use the libraries developed in `java` (Android), i have to create the DLLs(assemblies) using the `*.jar` file through the `binding project`.

And then refer those dlls in my `Xamarin Forms` project. As of now it works perfectly and no issues in it.

But while debug the source code(`i can't debug the native code directly`), i need to create new `jar` file and then create new `dll` for each line change.

Is there any other approach to debug the java code from `xamarin studio/visual studio`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a supported scenario. These are calls through the JNI and thus you should do your debugging on the Java end instead. Although it's possible to attach a debugger to a java process via Visual Studio, it may not be what you expect. It would be best to fully develop and test your `.jar/.aar` before creating a Binding project for consumption in Xamarin.Android.